# Magento 1.9 force language in url always

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I have a multistore language, lets say I have example.com with /en (english) and /fr (french). The default store is the french one.

So when somebody enters example.com he goes to the french store but the url remains example.com, and I need that only example.com/fr and example.com/en are available. So if somebody writes down example.com goes to example.com/fr automatically.

```
now I have that:
if you enter example.com    you go to example.com    in french.
if you enter example.com/fr you go to example.com/fr in french.
if you enter example.com/en you go to example.com/en in english.

I need that:
if you enter example.com    you go to example.com/fr in french
if you enter example.com/fr you go to example.com/fr in french.
if you enter example.com/en you go to example.com/en in english.
```

I have been searching, and I only see how to remove the language from the default store. But I need to add it always so nobody can go to the url without language.

I think it is not a good idea, but it is what I have to do.

PD: I have amasty geoip redirect installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it editing the index.php. The fr store id is 2, so the working code is:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
if ($storeId == 2) {
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if ($url=='/') {
        $url = 'fr';
        header("Location: $url");
        return;
    }
}
```

Personally, I don't like the solution, but it seems to work and it does not break the geoip redirections.

Comment: Are you using nginx for your server? You can achieve via nginx